# C# and WPF, when using mvvm style, and button action as command with commandparameter, how to ALWAYS create a new object in commandparameter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here is the xaml wpf in the `MainWindow`:

```
<Button
                    x:Name="Add_Button"
                    Content="Add Item"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ActionButtonStyle}"
                    Command="{Binding openAddDialogCommand}">
                    <Button.CommandParameter>
                        <local:MyDialog />
                    </Button.CommandParameter>
                </Button>
```

Here, the `MainWindow` has already a context with a ViewModel. `openAddDialogCommand` is a command to open it. The parameter itself will be passed as a `IDialogService`, not the dialog itself.

Now the problem is, `MyDialog` is a window, and when I closed it, the window can't be reopened, unless it's a new instance. How to always return a new instance as parameter? I tried using a variable in `MainWindow`class, which always generate a new object in its getter, then use binding to the button, it doesn't work at all unless I raise property changed, which is too complicated, and I don't want to add more code to `MainWindow` class. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Use a service call instead, separate window from being passed in as a parameter because you create a dependency for that command, which in turn will complicate the testing.

Comment: What does the command itself do? You could probably use a static command and avoid passing a piece of UI into the viewmodel at all. Make the commandparameter a type and then your static command would be generic.

Comment: Agreed. In MVVM there are no circumstances whatsoever in which a GUI element should ever be passed into a command handler. There are plenty of MVVM dialog box implementations around including [the one I wrote myself](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820324/%2FArticles%2F820324%2FImplementing-Dialog-Boxes-in-MVVM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the click event and *programmatically* create a new instance of `MyDialog` instead of using a command parameter:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = DataContext as viewModel:
    viewModel.openAddDialogCommand.Execute(new MyDialog());
}
```

This just invokes the very same command from the very same view but it's more flexible to do this using a programming language such as C# rather than using a markup language such as XAML.

MVVM is not about eliminating code from the views, it's mainly about separation of concerns.